# How to delete multiple files in gcs except 1 using gsutil

Tags: python, bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I currently have this: `gsutil ls gs://basty/*_TZ001.*`

```
gs://basty/20201007_TZ001.csv
gs://basty/20201008_TZ001.csv
gs://basty/20201009_TZ001.csv
```

My problem is that I have bcuket with many files I want to delete all except 1 (`20201009_TZ001.csv`)

I thought using bash or python I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter results with **grep** (using -v flag to invert results) and the pipe with **xargs**

```
gsutil ls gs://basty/*_TZ001.* |\
  grep -v 20201009_TZ001.csv |\
  xargs -i{} gsutil rm {}
```

To be sure that is precisely what you want, you could first execute a dry-run command:

```
gsutil ls gs://basty/*_TZ001.* |\
  grep -v 20201009_TZ001.csv |\
  xargs -i{} echo "Will delete: " {}
```

Comment: I get `illegal option -- i` on MacOS while testing it. It works if the [**xargs**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) flag is changed to `-I`

Answer (score 5):

I have another solution. This one is based on [**temporary holds**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/holding-objects#release-object-hold). I recommend you create a new folder inside the bucket. Then, add to this one a temporary hold like this:

```html
gsutil -m  retention temp set gs://BUCKETNAME/FOLDER/
```

Then, add all the files that you don't want to **delete** to this **Folder** .

Execute the command :

```html
gsutil rm gs://BUCKET/*
```

You will see how all the files will be erased skipping the **FOLDER**.

Finally, remove the hold:

```html
gsutil -m  retention temp release  gs://BUCKETNAME/FOLDER/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more solution

```
gsutil ls -r gs://basty/*_TZ001.* | grep -v 20201009_TZ001.csv | gsutil -m rm -I
```

- it works very fast as it removes files concurrently and not one by one (-m option in the command)
- it doesn't use holds which make the whole operation slower
- it works for files at any level in the bucket file structure if you replace `gs://basty/*_TZ001.*` with `gs://basty/**`